# crystal sort for last 12 months

Tags: c, crystal-reports

I am trying a create a crystal report for the monthly rate for twelve month showing in chart.

For this task, I have a `dc_date(mm/dd/yyyy)` as variable, which I changed in to a `mmyyyy` format. But when I see the group of month it starts always from `01_XXXX` which is not necessarily true.

For example, for the report running this `month(072013)` first month should be `062013` and last month should be `072012`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change the format to YYYYMM 
Hope this will help.

Comment: It helped exactly the way I wanted . Thank Alexs